# Is it possible to Inline an SVG in style.css for reuse, multiple times, as a background-image?

Tags: css, svg, lazy-loading

Essentially the footer on many pages of my websites, is 3 buttons.  In `style.css` I've styled them with a background svg.  This is problematic because I have multiple images at the top paused by `class="lazyload"` using `<script src="../lazysizes.min.js" async=""></script>`, so the browser is now prioritising loading 3 unimportant SVG images at the very bottom.

```
.button {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;background-size: contain}

.button{background-image:url("icon-values/gem.svg"), linear-gradient(to bottom right, silver, darkgrey)}
.button:hover {background-image:url("icon-values/gem.svg"), linear-gradient(to bottom right, #648DA2, #215c7a)}
```

I want to inline the svg code in `style.css` however you can see I use each svg twice, I use it again for the `button:hover` state.  I don't want to bloat out my styles.css with duplicate svg code.  Further I read that svgs aren't cached, so whenever the users goes to a new page it loads them again, and it may even load the svgs twice if the user `hovers` on any page - Good Lord!

I've tried Google, it has information on `<use xlink=""/>` but that's if you want to reuse an svg in the HTML body, there doesn't appear to be a way to inline SVG for reuse within style.css, or is there?

**Thanks to G-Cyrillus comment on css vars I used this:**

```
.buttonLeft{
background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center;background-size: contain;
--gem: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,.....BLOB....");
background-image:var(--gem), linear-gradient(to bottom right, silver, darkgrey)}

.buttonLeft:hover {background-image:var(--gem), linear-gradient(to bottom right, #648DA2, #215c7a)}
```

It switches the background gradient on a button on hover, but doesn't bloat up the CSS with another background images for the hover state.  PERFECT!

Comment: you can just convert it to a data URL so yes it's possible.

Comment: Hi Robert, I want to use it twice, without bloating the code with 2 inlined dataURL'd SVGs.  In fact it would be 6, because I have 3 buttons like this.  Normally you would use <def>?  Or something to reuse SVGs but how would I do that in style.css?

Comment: you either accept the bloat or you have a single external image. Pick your poison.

Comment: Understood, thanks for your attention Robert.

Comment: not too sure what you need, but would CSS var() would help to shorten your code  https://jsfiddle.net/84g2j7w9/ ?

Comment: Ah perfect @G-Cyrillus yes var() is what I needed, thanks for the fiddle.  I encoded my SVGs to base 64 and set it to a var, doesn't work in IE. but it's not critical that it do so, so this is a perfect solution.  I'll accept it as the answer if you would be so bold as to repost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(from earlier comment)*

You may use the css `var()` function to avoid repeating the same value and shorten the code .

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*
>
> Property names that are prefixed with --, like --example-name, represent custom properties that contain a value that can be used in other declarations using the var() function.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()
>
> The var() CSS function can be used to insert the value of a custom property (sometimes called a "CSS variable") instead of any part of a value of another property.

example for a background :

```css
html {
  --svg: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Green_circle.svg) no-repeat center;
  background: var(--svg) / 50%;
  filter : drop-shadow(0 0 5px);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  background: var(--svg) / 25%;
}

p {
  background: var(--svg) / 60%; 
  padding: 6em 3em;
  width:max-content
}
```

```html
<p>
  some more bg here
</p>
```